# Electron desktop APP GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY: Context has been lost

Tags: opengl, electron, window

Desktop APP based electron start up to meet the error on windows 7 pro, the console is full of logs:

```
[4688:0302/234755.270:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(325)] [.DisplayCompositor] GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY: Context has been lost.
[4688:0302/234755.271:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(325)] [.DisplayCompositor] GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY: Context has been lost.
[4688:0302/234755.274:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(325)] [.DisplayCompositor] GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY: Context has been lost.
[4688:0302/234755.275:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(325)] [.DisplayCompositor] GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY: Context has been lost.
electron: 7.1.7
electron-builder: ^22.2.0
electron-react-devtools: 0.5.3
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `--disable-gpu` to command line fix this problem for me in Windows 7, maybe a GPU-related problem.

See https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/21500

Comment: sorry to the late reply, it's useful. 3ks.